# How to input different email while automating a signup page?

Tags: java, selenium, methods, automation, webdriver

I am creating an automation script using Selenium WebDriver to automate a signup form and I want to run the script multiple times so every time I want the script to input different email addresses.

I am not fetching data from any excel sheet or database but rather I want a method to do this job. Please help me out!

Comment: Please share what you tried so far. Did you tried testng dataprovider it is the quickest?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TestNG` `DataProvider` mechanism. Please see code below:

First, create a method annotated by `@ataProvider`, like so:

```java
public class Data {
  @Test 
  @DataProvider(name="email")
  public Object[][] getData() {
    return new Object[][]
      {
        {"usrname1","pass1"},
        {"usrname2","pass2"},
      };
  }
}  
                                                                                                       Then, in the TestNG Class add:
```

```java
@Test(dataProvider="email",dataProviderClass=Data.class)
public void signUp(String username,String pass) throws InterruptedException {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("put here the xpath of username field']")).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("put xpath of passord field ]")).sendKeys(pass);
    Thread.sleep(1000);//i
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of login button")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath of logout button")).click();
```

The `@DataProvider` will provide all the arguments to the method annotated by `@Test` that uses it, so in that specific case one can see the `username` and `pass` arguments will take on `"usrname1"` and `"pass1"` on the first test iteration, and then `"usrname2"` and `"pass2"` on the second iteration.